# Limit number of records to be received from SAP using JCo library

Tags: java, jco

Suppose there are 100 records in one of the SAP tables and I want to access only 5 of them. When I call for BAPI function execution, it brings all 100 records in memory and then only I can iterate on them.

How to limit records to 5 before I execute BAPI function?

I cannot ask client to limit number of records in table itself, so I have code it using JCo library.

Comment: Share the code how do you call BAPI, and what BAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functionality like this would have to be implemented in the BAPI itself. In fact, some BAPIs have a WHERE clause that allows to limit the result set that the BAPI will return.

But "from the outside" (i.e. from the JCo layer) you cannot influence the result that the BAPI will return. At least not on such a fine granular level: there is the feature to "turn off" an entire table, which can be used, if you call a BAPI that returns dozens of tables (and spends lots of time selecting the data for them from the database), but you are interested only in a few of these tables. Then you can set the other tables to "inactive", and the RFC layer of the backend will only return the data for the active tables. (And if the BAPI is programmed in an intelligent way, it determines beforehand, which tables are active and skips the SELECT statements for the inactive ones.)

Here is a bit of sample code, that deactivates a BAPI's table with name "TABLE_NAME":

```
JCoFunction myBapi = ...;
JCoParameterList tables = myBapi.getTableParameterList();
tables.setActive("TABLE_NAME", false);
// Now you can execute myBapi, and the backend system will not return 
// data for the table named TABLE_NAME.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. It means limiting number of table is somehow possible but not limiting records in the table. Thanks.

Comment: I added some sample code that shows how to disable a certain table.

Comment: this is a great option to limit table data.. appreciate your help.. thanks..